# Draw text above a line on P5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm doing a graph theory project, and I need to show the edge weight above each of the edges.

currently I'm using this method:

```
var x1; //starting point
var x2; //ending point


function setup() {
    createCanvas(640, 480);
    x1 = createVector(random(0, width/2), random(0, height/2)); //random position to the upper left
    x2 = createVector(random(width/2, width), random(height/2, height)); //random position to the lower right
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    stroke(0);
    line(x1.x, x1.y, x2.x, x2.y); //draw a line beetween the points
    d = dist(x1.x, x1.y, x2.x, x2.y);
    var angle = atan2(x1.y - x2.y, x1.x - x2.x); // gets the angle of the line
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("X1", x1.x + 5, x1.y + 5); // just to show where is the begining
    text("X2", x2.x - 5, x2.y - 5); // just to show there is the end
    fill(0);
    signalx = x1.x > x2.x ? -1 : 1; // if the start is to the right of the end
    signaly = x1.y > x2.y ? -1 : 1; // if the start is below the end
    // I think i need to use the angle here
    text(42, (x1.x + (d / 2) * signalx), (x1.y + (d / 2) * signaly)); 
}
```

the problem is that the result, well, is not as expected:
[image: current result]

The idea is that the text I'm showing (`42`, the edge weight) is a little bit above the middle of the line, what is currently not happening.

I know that I have to take the angle of the line into consideration, but not sure where.

Thanks for any help, and if there's any need of more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use *linear interpolation*. First, find the equation of the line in slope-intercept form, so you can solve for y (when you know x). (I'm just going to rename `x1` to `p1` and `x2` to `p2` for clarity.)

```
(math)
// with points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)
y - y1 = m*(x - x1)  // point-slope form (just a step)
y - y1 = m*x - m*x1 
y = m*x - m*x1 + y1  // slope-intercept
```

Then, since x is the midpoint of the line, x equals the average of the two endpoints. And then calculate y, based on the above equation:

```
(code)
float m = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
int x = (x2 + x1) / 2;
int y = m*x - m*p1.x + p1.y;
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's what I needed. I wasn't sure how to calc that mid point (too many years away from math :D ). marking as solved.

Comment: That's when algebra comes in handy! :P